# static char *buf = NULL

Tags: c, variables, static

I'm new to programming and I have a project to do about static variables in C. I've seen that we can declare a static variable like this:

```
static char     *buf = NULL
```

What does it do to add  " = NULL " at the end?

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstddef/NULL/?kw=NULL

Comment: It looks like you need to pick up a book and start reading on many basic concepts.

Comment: @user2485710 Wrong language

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit open the page and read the labels for the tabs

Comment: @user2485710: Fair play

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the case of a `static` variable, it adds exactly nothing but a documentatory component: the author documents that the value is explicitly set to `NULL`.

The only (internal) difference is that, if such concepts exist,

```
static char *buf;
```

will be put into the `.bss` segment (resp. will be zeroed "in a run"), while

```
static char *buf = NULL;
```

might be put into `.data` (resp. might be initialized along with other, non-zero initialized variables).

("Might" means: a compiler can be free to choose to put it into `.bss` despite the initialization, as the effect is the same.)

Comment: It *might* be put into `.data` section, but it's up to compiler.

Comment: @haccks: Yes. `static`s are always zero-initialised before any other initialisation is performed. Reference is the standard, C99 6.7.8/10.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit; Thanks for the reference. Never knew that.

Comment: Thanks, so... I don't need to add " = NULL " when I declare    static char *buff, right ?

Comment: Concepts like `.bss` and `.data` segments are OS and compiler specific. In a general C context, and especially for a programming beginner, the first and the last sentence of the answer are relevant and spot-on.

Comment: @user4815162342 Right, but if no (such) segments exist, there will probably be a similiar concept.

Comment: @MysteriousStranger You don't need to, but if you want in order to document something, it won't hurt.

Comment: @MysteriousStranger: Correct, but what *glglglg* calls "*documentatory effect*" should not be underestimated.

Comment: Probably, although the bss segment can be thought of as a pure optimization on the part of the runtime. My point, though, was that it might be better not to confuse a beginner with such terms, but to introduce them later, and begin the answer with your first and last sentence. But it's your answer. :)

Comment: @user4815162342 You are right; I put the documentatory stuff to the top.

Comment: @Lightness Races in Orbit: "... before any other initialization is performed" part is completely inconsequential in C language. It is actually a quote from C++ spec that exists due to separation of C++ initialization into static and dynamic phases. In C initialization is always a one-shot process.

Answer (score -1):

to initialize  the ptr to `zero`
the same as

```
static char *buf = 0;
```

Answer (score -3):

It initialises that pointer with `NULL` at compile time. Otherwise its starting value is undefined.

Comment: No, not with `static`.